# Replace all using indexOf and while loop in String.prototype

Tags: javascript, string, replace, prototype, indexof

I am trying to implement in my code this string replacement function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(f,r) {
  if (f != r) {
    while (this.indexOf(f) !== -1) {
      this = this.replace(f,r);
    }
  } else {
    return this;
  }
};
```

And I already tried to use this:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(f,r) {
  return this.split(f).join(r);
};
```

But this last replacement function **does not work** with two or more characters in the search expression.

So I really need to use the first function with the while-loop.

**Does anybody knows what is the problem in the first function showed?**

Comment: well you're sort of cheating by using `String.prototype.replace` in the implementation. But you know you can use `string.replace(/find/g, 'replacement')` if you want to replace all, right ?

Comment: Tank you for the answer! I know that I can use /g and /gi. In fact, my code is already working using replace /g. But at some point I wanted to wirte a little function to nit be necessary using RegExp. But as we have seen, with no reason the while-loop did't work.

Comment: I provided a much more in-depth answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(f,r)
{
var str=this;
if (f != r) {
    while (str.indexOf(f) !== -1) {
       str=str.replace(f,r);
    }
}
return str.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript, so things like this won't work

```
// can't reassign `this` in String.prototype method !
this = this.replace(f,r)
```

Instead, you must return a new string from your function

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function replaceAll(f,r) {
  if (this.indexOf(f) === -1)
    return this.toString()
  else
    return this.replace(f, r).replaceAll(f,r)
}

console.log('foobar foobar'.replaceAll('foo', 'hello')) // => 'hellobar hellobar'
console.log('foobar foobar'.replaceAll('o', 'x'))       // => 'fxxbar fxxbar'
```

So that's the short answer if you don't mind relying upon built-ins like `String.prototype.indexOf` and `String.prototype.replace`

---

If you want to implement those from scratch too, you can do so with very basic JavaScript. You don't have to use a `while` loop`. You *can*, but a statement like …

> So I really need to use the first function with the while-loop.

… is false.

---

Let's start with a basic `find` function. This works like `String.prototype.indexOf`

```
function find(s, x) {
  function loop(s, pos) {
    if (s.substring(0, x.length) === x)
      return pos
    else if (s === '')
      return -1
    else
      return loop(s.substring(1), pos + 1)
  }
  return loop(s, 0)
}

console.log(find('foobar', 'f'))   // => 0
console.log(find('foobar', 'bar')) // => 3
console.log(find('foobar', 'x'))   // => -1
console.log(find('foobar', ''))    // => 0
```

Then a `replace` function which works to replace a single instance of `x` with `y` in string `s`

```
function replace(s, x, y, idx) {
  // idx is an optional parameter here for optimizing replaceAll
  // you'll see it used in the next example
  if (idx === undefined)
    return replace(s, x, y, find(s, x))
  else if (idx === -1)
    return s
  else
    return s.substring(0, idx) + y + s.substring(idx + x.length)
}

console.log(replace('foobar', 'foo', 'hello')) // => 'hellobar'
console.log(replace('foobar', 'bar', 'hello')) // => 'foohello'
```

Then, implementing `replaceAll` is a simple recursive function

```
function replaceAll(s, x, y) {
  var idx = find(s, x)
  if (idx === -1)
    return s
  else
    // use 4th parameter in replace function so index isn't recalculated
    return replaceAll(replace(s, x, y, idx), x, y)
}

console.log(replaceAll('foobar foobar', 'foo', 'hello')) // => 'hellobar hellobar'
console.log(replaceAll('foobar foobar', 'o', 'x')   )    // => 'fxxbar fxxbar'
```

---

You can implement all of these functions on `String.prototype` if you want, so things like `'foobar'.replaceAll('o', 'x')` would work.

If you don't like `find`, you can use the native `String.prototype.indexOf`. On the other hand, if you're doing this as an exercise and you're trying to implement it all from scratch, you can even go so far as to not rely upon `String.prototype.substring` that I have used here.

---

Also, for what it's worth, your code here works fine

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(f,r) {
  return this.split(f).join(r);
};

'foobar foobar'.replaceAll('foo', 'hello')
// => "hellobar hellobar"

'foobar foobar'.split('foo').join('hello')
// => "hellobar hellobar"
```

Comment: Thanks naomik! I hadn't paid attention that the `String` is a **Primitive Value**, so it's immutable (unlike `Array` and `Object`).